# Why my text got truncated in PDF in rails 3.1.12

Tags: pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have just upgraded my rails version last month from 3.0.6 to 3.1.12. Now i am working on an accounting application i need to send invoices in PDF format, for that i have used prawn, but i felt an issue my account description got truncated in PDF format, i don't know why?

Here is part of code for printing table data in invoice:

```
for i in @invoice_line_items
      data += [["#{i.item_name}","#{i.description}",{:content =>"#{i.quantity}",:align => :right},{:content => "#{i.unit_rate.to_s}", :align => :right},{:content => "#{i.discount_percent}", :align => :right},{:content => "#{i.amount.to_s}", :align => :right}]]
     end
```

Here is my screen shot :
1) PDF file:
[image: Here in PDF file my description got truncated]

2) View screen :[image: Here in view screen i have many lines in description]

Is any buddy have any idea what i am missing? As you can see i have many lines in view file but it is truncated in PDF format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Friends i found the solution of this problem, after inspecting my code carefully i found that i am using line hight property, due to that line has been truncated as per the size and my content also truncated and now i have removed that line height and everything is working fine